Convergence of right-continuous inverse on the Skorohod space
Let $D([0,\infty),[0,\infty))$ be the Skorohod space of càdlàg functions (where we care about the weak convergence of random variables with values in this space). Assume, that a sequence of stochastic processes $Z^N$ valued in this space (that may be assumed to be nondecreasing) converges weakly to a process $Z$. What can be said about the convergence of the right continuous inverses of the processes? Does it hold, that $(Z^N)^{-1} \Rightarrow Z^{-1}$? (where the inverse notation means right-continuous inverse (also called generalized inverse)).
